What is this movie where emperor from neighbouring country kills other in an invitation?
This movie is very current (post 2000). I remember I deleted the movie from my laptop because it had too much adult scenes like bed scenes etc. The broken parts which I remember are as follows:
1) The movie had an essence of Roman era Gladiators etc.
2) Two countries have been fighting from long time ago (?). One country then thinks to invite the other country to make friend. The other country comes with the emperor himself. The host countries emperor offers his queen to do sex with the invited emperor. Although, the invited emperor chooses the sister of the queen over the queen (Most probably it was planned by the queen herself). All the invited persons who came with the emperor also enjoy a grand party along with grandeurous eating, dance and sex with most probably any girl they want to pick!
3) At the end it is revealed the invited emperor had an ill plan. He killed the host countries army when they were sleeping. We all see that from the POV of the queen. The sister is also killed in this process!
4) The movie as far as I can remember was most probably part 2 of some franchisee! (Of course, not so popular!)
I do not remember exactly what I have cited above. A little bit of change may be possible!

Aha! Remembered one of the actors; it was John Hannah. This was a TV mini series named Spartacus: Gods of the Arena. Probably it was part 2 of Spartacus Vengeance. It had explicit sex and violence. The queen and the sister I was talking about is in this picture.
. The explicit sex scenes which I was referring to can be found in this Google search (Not posting the pics considering explicit nudity).

I also immediately thought about Spartacus when reading the question, considering the many sex scenes this show has.

@ChristianRau, I would request you to join this room so that we can discuss on the matter of Nolan question!
